# Question already has answer, but not marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555742/generating-sourcemaps-when-minifying-with-the-asp-net-web-optimization-framework)

I don't understand the logic here. The OP clearly states that the question is a duplicate of the question they link. Why then was my "flag as duplicate" flag answered with "not a duplicate"
?

If the question is *not* a duplicate, doesn't it need an answer, even if that answer comes from the OP?

Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Please clarify "ignored". Was the flag rejected or is it awaiting review?

Comment: I raised the flag and it already has an answer.

Comment: edited OP to correct ambiguity of "ignored"

Comment: Your flag wasn't *answered* as anything... It put the post in the close review queue and no one there got around to saying they agreed with you... So it just *aged away* (which it actually says next to it if you look at your flag history)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I can't find my flag history.

Comment: Gotcha, so what's the correct course of action in this case?

Comment: Or should my comment be a new question?

Comment: Well - it's getting a bit of attention from the "meta-effect" - allow the time for the OP to clarify if it is a dupe that solved his question or not... Or others can clarify even if it's not a great dupe - whether it's a valid dupe etc...

Comment: @FuriousFolder For you?  Do nothing.  You cast your flag; the question may end up being closed, or it may not.

Comment: The volume of questions marked as potential duplicate is always fairly high, some will inevitably fall through the cracks. The correct course of action is to just move on. One cannot possibly see it through on every community moderation task.

Comment: Haha, fair 'nough; I'm fairly new to the "Meta Game", but I'll leave well enough alone

Comment: Well... it appears your question has the desired effect - it's now closed by the community.

Comment: Eek. Wasn't trying to bully the OP or anything.. my goal was to improve SO :S 
That being said, what's the correct course of action for this meta question? Do i flag it as closed? Do i delete it?

Comment: If someone is obviously violating the rules, or being blatantly abusive, I'd follow up, make a meta post, etc. Duplicates are kind of low-level infractions, even though it does create serious clutter. There are organized efforts for some tags, but by and large it has to be something you look at as an incremental hot mess. Look at abusive activity as Murder 1, duplicate posting as 5-over the speed limit. The cops don't start a car chase for a moving violation (well.... usually).

Comment: This post will just kind of... age away. No worries.